Model Accuracy for Non-linear Relationship with Logarithm Kernel and Exponential Activation can't reach 100%
I'm working on a project where I need to model a non-linear relationship using a neural network. The relationship is ( y = 3x_1^2x_2^3 ). The network setup is as follows:

Preprocessing: Natural logarithm of inputs
Network Design: Single layer with one neuron
Activation Function: Exponential
Loss Function: MAE (Mean Absolute Error)
Optimizer: Adam
Epochs: 50
Batch Size: 32

Input and Expected Output:

Input: ([x1, x2])
Correct weights: ([2, 3])
Correct bias: (\ln 3)

Despite these settings, I am not able to achieve 100% accuracy. I've tried initializing weights and biases randomly as well as with specific values.
Here is the code:
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

# Generate data
x1 = np.random.randint(1, 21, size=(1000, 1))
x2 = np.random.randint(1, 21, size=(1000, 1))
y = 3 * (x1 ** 2) * (x2 ** 3)

# Preprocess data
log_x1 = np.log(x1)
log_x2 = np.log(x2)
log_inputs = np.hstack((log_x1, log_x2))

# Define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=2, activation='exponential', kernel_initializer='ones', bias_initializer='zeros'))

# Compile model
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.01), loss='mae')

# Train model
model.fit(log_inputs, np.log(y), epochs=50, batch_size=32)

# Evaluate model
test_x1 = np.array([[2], [4], [5]])
test_x2 = np.array([[3], [7], [19]])
test_inputs = np.hstack((np.log(test_x1), np.log(test_x2)))
predicted = model.predict(test_inputs)
print(np.exp(predicted))

Does anyone have suggestions on how to improve the accuracy of this model?

You seem to mixing some things up here. The model contains an exponential at the end, so the targets should be y, not log(y), OR you need to remove the exponential in the model. Also, if you have an exponential in the model, it is incorrect to use np.exp again after predict. This version works fine:
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

# Generate data
x1 = np.random.randint(1, 21, size=(1000, 1))
x2 = np.random.randint(1, 21, size=(1000, 1))
y = 3 * (x1 ** 2) * (x2 ** 3)

# Preprocess data
log_x1 = np.log(x1)
log_x2 = np.log(x2)
log_inputs = np.hstack((log_x1, log_x2))

# Define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=2, kernel_initializer='ones', bias_initializer='zeros'))

# Compile model
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.01), loss='mae')

# Train model
model.fit(log_inputs, np.log(y), epochs=100, batch_size=32)

# Evaluate model
test_x1 = np.array([[2], [4], [5]])
test_x2 = np.array([[3], [7], [19]])
test_inputs = np.hstack((np.log(test_x1), np.log(test_x2)))
predicted = model.predict(test_inputs)
print(np.exp(predicted))

